# A function that display the same text with two letters reversed

Tags: java, arrays, algorithm, encryption

I'm trying to make an encryptor.What i want it to do:

> Get the text i enter and reverse the first two letters of every word
>   and then display it again.

I have tried a lot of ways.This is the last one i've tried:

```
 private void TranslateToEf(){
        String storage = Display.getText();
        String[] arr = storage.split("\\W+");

        for ( String ss : arr) {

            char c[] = ss.toCharArray();
            char temp = c[0];
            c[0] = c[1];
            c[1] = temp;
            String swappedString = new String(c);
            Display.appendText(swappedString + " ");    
        }      
    }
```

Comment: Has this approach worked?

Comment: No.It displays blank.But many ways only worked with the first word.

Comment: Can you post an example input and output?

Comment: can you post example?

Comment: I edited with new code.If i enter Hello World i want it to return : ehllo owrld.

Comment: This is how it works now.http://gyazo.com/75581551b34194ed3813c9f64e84cd0d

Comment: Well, then it's ok and you answered your question yourself?

Comment: That's not how it should work

Comment: It looks like it does what you said you wanted. But in your example, turning "Hello World" into "ehllo owrld", you're not just swapping letters, you're changing case as well. Is that what you need?

Comment: @AlexSS you try with my answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You may want to consider maintaining all the delimiters lost from the first `String.split("\\W+")` so they can be included in the final result.  I would do that with a `String.split("\\w+")`

You may also want to consider that when you swap the first two letters, if the first letter is capital it becomes lowercase and the second letter becomes uppercase. Otherwise, just do a direct swap.

Code sample:

```
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
    String data = "Hello;World! My name is John. I write code.";
    String[] words = data.split("\\W+");
    String[] delimiters = data.split("\\w+");
    int delimiterIndex = 0;

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    for (String word : words) {
        if (word.length() < 2) {
            sb.append(word);
        } else {
            char firstLetter = word.charAt(0);
            char secondLetter = word.charAt(1);
            if (Character.isUpperCase(firstLetter)) {
                // Swap the first two letters and change casing
                sb.append(Character.toUpperCase(secondLetter))
                        .append(Character.toLowerCase(firstLetter));
            } else {
                // Swap the first two letters
                sb.append(secondLetter)
                        .append(firstLetter);
            }
            // Append the rest of the word past the first two letters
            sb.append(word.substring(2));
        }

        // Append delimiters
        if (delimiterIndex < delimiters.length) {
            // Skip blank delimiters if there are any
            while (delimiters[delimiterIndex].isEmpty()) {
                delimiterIndex++;
            }
            // Append delimiter
            sb.append(delimiters[delimiterIndex++]);
        }
    }
    data = sb.toString();

    // Display result
    System.out.println(data);
}
```

Results:

```
Ehllo;Owrld! Ym anme si Ojhn. I rwite ocde.
```

Answer (score 3):

```
public class Encrypto {


    public static void main(String[] args) {
        String input="Hello World";

        String [] word = input.split(" ");
    //  System.out.println(word[0]);
        String encryWord="";

        for(int i=0;i<word.length;i++){

            if (word[i].length() > 0) {
                String tmp0 = String.valueOf(word[i].charAt(1));
                String tmp1 = String.valueOf(word[i].charAt(0));

                encryWord += tmp0.toLowerCase() + tmp1.toLowerCase() + word[i].substring(2) + " ";
            }else{
                encryWord +=word[i];
        }   



        }
        System.out.println(encryWord);
    }

}
```

I think answer is more helpful for you

Comment: What'll happen if a word has only 1 character?

Comment: @Shar1er80 give error but we can check condition word[i].length>0 if condition true give statements else give error message

Comment: Why give an error?  Just handle the situation and don't do any swapping on a 1 character word.

Answer (score 1):

There are a few problems.

1. Declare `zz` outside the loop if you want to use it outside.
2. **Append** `zz` on every iteration. Not just **assign** it.

Something like this,

```
 private void TranslateToEf(){
        String storage = Display.getText();
        String[] arr = storage.split("\\W+");
        String zz = "";

        for ( String ss : arr) {

            char c[] = ss.toCharArray();
            char temp = c[0];
            c[0] = c[1];
            c[1] = temp;
            String swappedString = new String(c);
            String b= " ";
            zz += swappedString + b;      
        }
        Display.setText(zz + " ");      
    }
```

3. You are splitting with non-word (`\W+`) characters, but replacing it only with a space `" "`. This could alter the string with special characters.

Answer (score 0):

In Java strings are immutable. You can't modify them "on the fly", you need to reassign them to a new instance.

Additionally, you are setting the last display text to zz, but zz is a local variable to your loop, and therefore it gets re-instantiated with every iteration. In other words, you would be assigning to display only the last word!

Here is what you have to do to make it work:

```
String storage = Display.getText();
String[] arr = storage.split("\\W+");
String[] newText = new String[arr.length];
for ( int i = 0; i<arr.length; i++) {
  String original = arr[i];
  String modified = ((char) original.charAt(1)) + ((char) original.charAt(0)) + original.substring(2);
   newText[i] = modified;
}
//Join with spaces
String modifiedText = Arrays.asList(newText).stream().collect(Collectors.join(" "));
Display.setText(modifiedText);
```

Note that:
1) We are assuming all strings have at least 2 chars
2) that your splitting logic is correct. Can you think some edge cases where your regexp fails?

Comment: @AlexSS forgot to cast the chars. fixed now

Answer (score 0):

Not sure what exactly you are looking for but i little modification in your code see if this suits your needs

```
    String storage = "Test test t";
    String[] arr = storage.split("\\W+");

    String abc = "";
    for ( String ss : arr) {

        if(ss.length() > 1)
        {
            char c[] = ss.toCharArray();
            char temp = c[0];
            c[0] = c[1];
            c[1] = temp;
            String swappedString = new String( c );
            String b = " ";
            String zz = swappedString + b;
            abc = abc + zz;
        }else{
            abc = abc + ss;
        }
    }
    System.out.println(abc);
```